# Syntax and different meanings of '<letter>'

Tags: c, arrays

I am learning C from the K&R book and I came across the code to count the no. of occurrence of white space characters (blank, tab, newline) and of all other characters.
The code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];  
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
    nwhite, nother);
}
```

I need to ask 2 questions..
1st question:

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

I very well know that '0' and '9'represents the ASCII value of 0 & 9 respectively. But what I don't seem to understand is why we even need to use the ASCII vale and not the integer itself. Like why can't we simply use

```
if (c >= 0 && c <= 9)
```

to find if c lies between 0 and 9?

2nd question:

```
++ndigit[c-'0']
```

What does the above statement do?
Why aren't we taking the ASCII value of c here?
Because if we did, it should have been written as `['c'-'0']`.

Comment: `getchar` returns an ASCII value, which is stored in variable `c`.

Comment: please fix the formatting of your code

Comment: `for` and `while` body without `{}` is preparing yourself for for nasty future bugs.

Comment: In the future, please take the advice Stephen gave. Misformatting your code and wrong indentatin will confuse you, hide errors, make debugging harder and annoy otherwise helpful potential aswerers. And I count the advice by blueCat among that, short cuts by skipping (admittedly unneeded) `{}` does practically the same.

Comment: "I am learning C from the K&R book" `<horribly written code follows>`. This makes me sad. Whoever gave you this book didn't do you a favour. Please don't read this completely outdated book from the 1970s. In particular, do not adopt their horrible, dangerous, unreadable coding style.

Comment: If you *actually* understand the difference between character codes and arithmetic numbers, your questions don't make sense. Perhaps you are really confused about something else, like what a variable is, or in which order the statements of a program are evaluated?

Comment: see this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210606/is-there-an-advantage-for-a-c-programmer-to-have-read-kr#210608, and take some other way to learn C: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

1.
C is a character, not an integer. Thus we need to compare them to their ASCII values. The integers 0 and 9 correspond to `Nul` and `Tab`, not something we are looking for.

2.
By subtracting off the ASCII value the index corresponding to the integer is increased. For example if our number is `'1'`. Then `'1' - '0' = 1` so the index at one is increased, its a convenient way to keep track of characters. We dont put `['c' - '0']` because we care about the variable `c` not the character `'c'`

This table shows how characters are represented, they are different from integers. The main take away is `'1' != 1`
http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

With the current C standards, this would be a perfect exercise for *localized wide input*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include "wdigit.h"

int main(void)
{
    size_t  num_space = 0; /* Spaces, tabs, newlines */
    size_t  num_letter = 0;
    size_t  num_punct = 0; /* Punctuation */
    size_t  num_digit[10] = { 0, }; /* Digits - all initialized to zero */
    size_t  num_other = 0; /* Other printable characters */
    size_t  total = 0;
    wint_t  wc;
    int     digit;

    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, "")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Current locale is not supported by the C library.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (fwide(stdin, 1) < 1) {  
        fprintf(stderr, "The C library does not support wide input for this locale.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((wc = fgetwc(stdin)) != WEOF) {
        total++;
        digit = wdigit(wc);
        if (digit >= 0 && digit <= 9)
            num_digit[digit]++;
        else
        if (iswspace(wc))
            num_space++;
        else
        if (iswpunct(wc))
            num_punct++;
        else
        if (iswalpha(wc))
            num_letter++;
        else
        if (iswprint(wc))
            num_other++;
        /* All nonprintable non-whitespace characters are ignored */
    }

    printf("Read %zu wide characters total.\n", total);
    printf("%15zu letters\n", num_letter);
    printf("%15zu zeros (equivalent to '0')\n", num_digit[0]);
    printf("%15zu ones (equivalent to '1')\n", num_digit[1]);
    printf("%15zu twos (equivalent to '2')\n", num_digit[2]);
    printf("%15zu threes (equivalent to '3')\n", num_digit[3]);
    printf("%15zu fours (equivalent to '4')\n", num_digit[4]);
    printf("%15zu fives (equivalent to '5')\n", num_digit[5]);
    printf("%15zu sixes (equivalent to '6')\n", num_digit[6]);
    printf("%15zu sevens (equivalent to '7')\n", num_digit[7]);
    printf("%15zu eights (equivalent to '8')\n", num_digit[8]);
    printf("%15zu nines (equivalent to '9')\n", num_digit[9]);
    printf("%15zu whitespaces (including newlines and tabs)\n", num_space);
    printf("%15zu punctuation characters\n", num_punct);
    printf("%15zu other printable characters\n", num_other);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You also need **wdigit.h**, a header file that returns the decimal digit value (0 to 9, inclusive) if the given wide character is a decimal digit, and -1 otherwise.  If this was an exercise, the header file would be provided.

The following `"wdigit.h"` should support all decimal digits defined in Unicode (which is the closest standard we have to an universal character set).  I don't think it is copyrightable (because it is essentially just a listing from the Unicode standard), but if it is, I [dedicate it to public domain](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/):

```
#ifndef   WDIGIT_H
#define   WDIGIT_H
#include <wchar.h>

/* wdigits[] are wide strings that contain all known versions of a decimal digit.
   For example, wdigits[0] is a wide string that contains all known zero decimal digit
   wide characters.  You can use e.g.
       wcschr(wdigits[0], wc)
   to determine if wc is a zero decimal digit wide character.
*/
static const wchar_t *const wdigits[10] = {
    L"0"  L"\u0660\u06F0\u07C0\u0966\u09E6\u0A66\u0AE6\u0B66\u0BE6\u0C66"
          L"\u0CE6\u0D66\u0DE6\u0E50\u0ED0\u0F20\u1040\u1090\u17E0\u1810"
          L"\u1946\u19D0\u1A80\u1A90\u1B50\u1BB0\u1C40\u1C50\uA620\uA8D0"
          L"\uA900\uA9D0\uA9F0\uAA50\uABF0\uFF10"
          L"\U000104A0\U00011066\U000110F0\U00011136\U000111D0\U000112F0"
          L"\U00011450\U000114D0\U00011650\U000116C0\U00011730\U000118E0"
          L"\U00011C50\U00011D50\U00016A60\U00016B50\U0001D7CE\U0001D7D8"
          L"\U0001D7E2\U0001D7EC\U0001D7F6\U0001E950",
    L"1"  L"\u0661\u06F1\u07C1\u0967\u09E7\u0A67\u0AE7\u0B67\u0BE7\u0C67"
          L"\u0CE7\u0D67\u0DE7\u0E51\u0ED1\u0F21\u1041\u1091\u17E1\u1811"
          L"\u1947\u19D1\u1A81\u1A91\u1B51\u1BB1\u1C41\u1C51\uA621\uA8D1"
          L"\uA901\uA9D1\uA9F1\uAA51\uABF1\uFF11"
          L"\U000104A1\U00011067\U000110F1\U00011137\U000111D1\U000112F1"
          L"\U00011451\U000114D1\U00011651\U000116C1\U00011731\U000118E1"
          L"\U00011C51\U00011D51\U00016A61\U00016B51\U0001D7CF\U0001D7D9"
          L"\U0001D7E3\U0001D7ED\U0001D7F7\U0001E951",
    L"2"  L"\u0662\u06F2\u07C2\u0968\u09E8\u0A68\u0AE8\u0B68\u0BE8\u0C68"
          L"\u0CE8\u0D68\u0DE8\u0E52\u0ED2\u0F22\u1042\u1092\u17E2\u1812"
          L"\u1948\u19D2\u1A82\u1A92\u1B52\u1BB2\u1C42\u1C52\uA622\uA8D2"
          L"\uA902\uA9D2\uA9F2\uAA52\uABF2\uFF12"
          L"\U000104A2\U00011068\U000110F2\U00011138\U000111D2\U000112F2"
          L"\U00011452\U000114D2\U00011652\U000116C2\U00011732\U000118E2"
          L"\U00011C52\U00011D52\U00016A62\U00016B52\U0001D7D0\U0001D7DA"
          L"\U0001D7E4\U0001D7EE\U0001D7F8\U0001E952",
    L"3"  L"\u0663\u06F3\u07C3\u0969\u09E9\u0A69\u0AE9\u0B69\u0BE9\u0C69"
          L"\u0CE9\u0D69\u0DE9\u0E53\u0ED3\u0F23\u1043\u1093\u17E3\u1813"
          L"\u1949\u19D3\u1A83\u1A93\u1B53\u1BB3\u1C43\u1C53\uA623\uA8D3"
          L"\uA903\uA9D3\uA9F3\uAA53\uABF3\uFF13"
          L"\U000104A3\U00011069\U000110F3\U00011139\U000111D3\U000112F3"
          L"\U00011453\U000114D3\U00011653\U000116C3\U00011733\U000118E3"
          L"\U00011C53\U00011D53\U00016A63\U00016B53\U0001D7D1\U0001D7DB"
          L"\U0001D7E5\U0001D7EF\U0001D7F9\U0001E953",
    L"4"  L"\u0664\u06F4\u07C4\u096A\u09EA\u0A6A\u0AEA\u0B6A\u0BEA\u0C6A"
          L"\u0CEA\u0D6A\u0DEA\u0E54\u0ED4\u0F24\u1044\u1094\u17E4\u1814"
          L"\u194A\u19D4\u1A84\u1A94\u1B54\u1BB4\u1C44\u1C54\uA624\uA8D4"
          L"\uA904\uA9D4\uA9F4\uAA54\uABF4\uFF14"
          L"\U000104A4\U0001106A\U000110F4\U0001113A\U000111D4\U000112F4"
          L"\U00011454\U000114D4\U00011654\U000116C4\U00011734\U000118E4"
          L"\U00011C54\U00011D54\U00016A64\U00016B54\U0001D7D2\U0001D7DC"
          L"\U0001D7E6\U0001D7F0\U0001D7FA\U0001E954",
    L"5"  L"\u0665\u06F5\u07C5\u096B\u09EB\u0A6B\u0AEB\u0B6B\u0BEB\u0C6B"
          L"\u0CEB\u0D6B\u0DEB\u0E55\u0ED5\u0F25\u1045\u1095\u17E5\u1815"
          L"\u194B\u19D5\u1A85\u1A95\u1B55\u1BB5\u1C45\u1C55\uA625\uA8D5"
          L"\uA905\uA9D5\uA9F5\uAA55\uABF5\uFF15"
          L"\U000104A5\U0001106B\U000110F5\U0001113B\U000111D5\U000112F5"
          L"\U00011455\U000114D5\U00011655\U000116C5\U00011735\U000118E5"
          L"\U00011C55\U00011D55\U00016A65\U00016B55\U0001D7D3\U0001D7DD"
          L"\U0001D7E7\U0001D7F1\U0001D7FB\U0001E955",
    L"6"  L"\u0666\u06F6\u07C6\u096C\u09EC\u0A6C\u0AEC\u0B6C\u0BEC\u0C6C"
          L"\u0CEC\u0D6C\u0DEC\u0E56\u0ED6\u0F26\u1046\u1096\u17E6\u1816"
          L"\u194C\u19D6\u1A86\u1A96\u1B56\u1BB6\u1C46\u1C56\uA626\uA8D6"
          L"\uA906\uA9D6\uA9F6\uAA56\uABF6\uFF16"
          L"\U000104A6\U0001106C\U000110F6\U0001113C\U000111D6\U000112F6"
          L"\U00011456\U000114D6\U00011656\U000116C6\U00011736\U000118E6"
          L"\U00011C56\U00011D56\U00016A66\U00016B56\U0001D7D4\U0001D7DE"
          L"\U0001D7E8\U0001D7F2\U0001D7FC\U0001E956",
    L"7"  L"\u0667\u06F7\u07C7\u096D\u09ED\u0A6D\u0AED\u0B6D\u0BED\u0C6D"
          L"\u0CED\u0D6D\u0DED\u0E57\u0ED7\u0F27\u1047\u1097\u17E7\u1817"
          L"\u194D\u19D7\u1A87\u1A97\u1B57\u1BB7\u1C47\u1C57\uA627\uA8D7"
          L"\uA907\uA9D7\uA9F7\uAA57\uABF7\uFF17"
          L"\U000104A7\U0001106D\U000110F7\U0001113D\U000111D7\U000112F7"
          L"\U00011457\U000114D7\U00011657\U000116C7\U00011737\U000118E7"
          L"\U00011C57\U00011D57\U00016A67\U00016B57\U0001D7D5\U0001D7DF"
          L"\U0001D7E9\U0001D7F3\U0001D7FD\U0001E957",
    L"8"  L"\u0668\u06F8\u07C8\u096E\u09EE\u0A6E\u0AEE\u0B6E\u0BEE\u0C6E"
          L"\u0CEE\u0D6E\u0DEE\u0E58\u0ED8\u0F28\u1048\u1098\u17E8\u1818"
          L"\u194E\u19D8\u1A88\u1A98\u1B58\u1BB8\u1C48\u1C58\uA628\uA8D8"
          L"\uA908\uA9D8\uA9F8\uAA58\uABF8\uFF18"
          L"\U000104A8\U0001106E\U000110F8\U0001113E\U000111D8\U000112F8"
          L"\U00011458\U000114D8\U00011658\U000116C8\U00011738\U000118E8"
          L"\U00011C58\U00011D58\U00016A68\U00016B58\U0001D7D6\U0001D7E0"
          L"\U0001D7EA\U0001D7F4\U0001D7FE\U0001E958",
    L"9"  L"\u0669\u06F9\u07C9\u096F\u09EF\u0A6F\u0AEF\u0B6F\u0BEF\u0C6F"
          L"\u0CEF\u0D6F\u0DEF\u0E59\u0ED9\u0F29\u1049\u1099\u17E9\u1819"
          L"\u194F\u19D9\u1A89\u1A99\u1B59\u1BB9\u1C49\u1C59\uA629\uA8D9"
          L"\uA909\uA9D9\uA9F9\uAA59\uABF9\uFF19"
          L"\U000104A9\U0001106F\U000110F9\U0001113F\U000111D9\U000112F9"
          L"\U00011459\U000114D9\U00011659\U000116C9\U00011739\U000118E9"
          L"\U00011C59\U00011D59\U00016A69\U00016B59\U0001D7D7\U0001D7E1"
          L"\U0001D7EB\U0001D7F5\U0001D7FF\U0001E959",
};

static int wdigit(const wint_t  wc)
{
    int  i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (wcschr(wdigits[i], wc))
            return i;
    return -1;
}

#endif /* WDIGIT_H */
```

On a Linux, *BSD, or Mac machine, you can compile the above using e.g.

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic example.c -o example
```

or

```
clang -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic example.c -o example
```

and test it using e.g.

```
printf 'Bengali decimal digit five is ৫.\n' | ./example
```

which outputs

```
Read 33 wide characters total.
         25 letters
          0 zeros (equivalent to '0')
          0 ones (equivalent to '1')
          0 twos (equivalent to '2')
          0 threes (equivalent to '3')
          0 fours (equivalent to '4')
          1 fives (equivalent to '5')
          0 sixes (equivalent to '6')
          0 sevens (equivalent to '7')
          0 eights (equivalent to '8')
          0 nines (equivalent to '9')
          6 whitespaces (including newlines and tabs)
          1 punctuation characters
          0 other printable characters
```

The above code is fully compliant to ISO C99 (and later versions of the ISO C standard), and should be completely portable.

However, note that not all C libraries fully support C99; the main one people have issues with is Microsoft C. I don't use Windows myself, but if you are, try using the UTF-8 codepage (`chcp 65001`). This is wholly and completely a Microsoft issue, as it apparently *can* support UTF-8 input with some nonstandard Windows extensions. They just don't want you to write portable code, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

**I need to ask 2 questions..**

**1st question:** I very well know that '0' and '9'represents the ASCII value of 0 & 9 respectively. But what I don't seem to understand is why we even need to use the ASCII vale and not the integer itself. Like why can't we simply use

```
if (c >= 0 && c <= 9)
```

Let's start with basics. All user input, file input, etc. is given in *characters*, so when you need to compare the character you have just read, it must be compared against another *character*. Within the character set, digits `0-9` are represented with ASCII values `48-57`, so character `'0'` is represented by `48`, and so on.

Your test above tests whether `c` is a digit, an ASCII value between `48-57`, so you must use the characters themselves within the comparison, e.g. `if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')` you then know `c` is a digit. This brings us to:

**2nd question:**

```
++ndigit[c-'0']
```

In any *classification* problem you do, you will generally use an array initialized to all zero with at least enough elements for the set (of characters here). You can split them out as an array of ten elements to hold your digits, uppercase, lowercase, etc...

Your `ndigit` array, begins initialized to all zeros, the plan is to increment the proper element in the array each time a digit is encountered during your read. This is where you make use of the ASCII value for the bottom of the digits `'0'` (48). Since your `ndigit` array is likely indexed `0-9` each time a digit is encountered it must be scaled (or mapped) into the correct index of `ndigit` (so that `'0'` is mapped to `0`, `'1'` mapped to `1`, and so on.

Above through your test we determined, in this case, that c held a digit, so to classify that digit and have it map to the correct element of the `ndigit` array, we use `c - '0'`. If the digit in `c` is `'3'` (ASCII `51`), then incrementing

```
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

is actually indexing

```
++ndigit[51 - 48];
```

or

```
++ndigit[3];   /* since c was 3, we no increment ndigit[3] adding one more
                  occurrence of '3' to the data stored at ndigit[3] */
```

That way when you are done, the `ndigit` array will hold the exact number of `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...` digits found in your input. It takes a bit to wrap your head around the scheme, but all in all, you simply need somewhere to begin counting from zero to store the totals for each character, digits, punctuations, seen, and an array that is sized for the character set will hold these values exactly when you are done because each character has been classified, and the corresponding `++ndigits[]` element incremented to capture the information as you went along.

These, in a general sense, are called *frequency arrays* because they are used to store the frequency with which the individual members of a set appeared. They are many, many applications outside simply classifying characters.

Look all of the answers over and let me know if you are still confused and I'm more than happy to help further.

Answer (score 0):

1. `getchar()` returns character codes and sentinel values (EOF). So, we know `c` holds a character code inside the loop.
2. `c-'0'` is the distance on the character code "number line" from the value of c (a character code) to the code for '0'. Per the C standard, character codes must have these digits in consecutive order '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'. So, the expression computes the integer value of the digit character.